# How does this code work?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I've found this code below, but I can't figure out how it works. Can someone explain to me the flow of the program?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 10, 7, 5, 4);
int mem=0;
void setup() {
    pinMode (12,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
    // initialize the LED pin as an output:

    // initialize serial communications:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {

    lcd.setCursor(12,1);
    int se25 = analogRead(A4);  
    int se50 = analogRead(A3); 
    int se75 = analogRead(A5);
    int se100 = analogRead(A2);  
    if(se100>=1000){lcd.print("100%   ");mem=100; }  
    else if(se75>=1000){lcd.print("75%   ");mem=75; } 
    else if(se50>=1000){lcd.print("50%   ");mem=50; }
    else if(se25>=1000){lcd.print("25%  ");mem=25; }
    else{lcd.print("emty");mem=0;}
    if(se100<1000&&se75<1000&&se50<1000&&se25<1000){
        digitalWrite(13,LOW);
        lcd.setCursor(12,1);
        lcd.print("emty");
    }

    if(digitalRead(6)==HIGH){digitalWrite(13,LOW);}

    if(digitalRead(6)==LOW&&mem>0) 
    {// read the value of the potentiometer:
        int tempw = 0;
        //digitalWrite(12,LOW);
        int tempa = analogRead(A1);
        delay(20); 
        int tempb = analogRead(A1);
        delay(20); 
        int tempc = analogRead(A1);
        delay(20); 
        int tempd = analogRead(A1);
        delay(20); 
        int tempe = analogRead(A1);
        delay(20); 
        int tempf = analogRead(A1);
        delay(20); 

        int avg = ((tempa + tempb + tempc + tempd + tempe + tempf ) / 6);

        int temp = avg;  
        // map it to the range of the analog out:
        temp = map(temp, 0, 1023, 0, 4900); 
        float tempx = temp * (0.1); 
        // change the analog out value:
        int tempy=analogRead(A0);
        tempy = map(tempy, 0, 1023, 0, 150);
        // print the results to the serial monitor:
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("act T=" ); 
        lcd.print(tempx);
        lcd.print("'C  " );
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("set T=");  

        lcd.print(tempy);  
        // Serial.println("'C ");
        lcd.print("'C  "); 

        if(tempy<=tempx){digitalWrite(13,LOW);}
        if(tempy>tempx){digitalWrite(13,HIGH);}

        delay(200);
    }

}
```

Comment: who voted this down? This is a legit question from a new user.

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you already have some understanding of programming, so I won't literally explain everything line-by-line (that would probably be beyond the scope of this site, and would result in a very long answer). I'll try to explain the important points though. If you need to lookup more information about specific commands, I recommend checking out the [Arduino reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference).

At a very broad level, the program is taking some readings, and reporting data to a screen (LCD). I would guess that the data is the fluid level in a tank, as well as some kind of temperature reading. It's impossible to be sure about that though, as I don't know what's actually connected to the inputs.

This line creates an object for talking to the LCD screen. The numbers specify which pins it's connected to:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 10, 7, 5, 4);
```

The `setup()` function gets run once when the device starts up, and is typically used for initialisation tasks. In this case, the lines within `setup()` initialise two pins as outputs (#12 and #13), initialise serial communication (which isn't actually being used), and initialise the LCD object/screen:

```
pinMode (12,OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
...
Serial.begin(9600);
lcd.begin(16, 2);
```

The rest of the program is in the `loop()` function, which runs repeatedly as long as the device is on.

The following lines take 4 analog-to-digital readings (from different inputs), and output the approximate result:

```
int se25 = analogRead(A4);  
int se50 = analogRead(A3); 
int se75 = analogRead(A5);
int se100 = analogRead(A2);  
if(se100>=1000){lcd.print("100%   ");mem=100; }  
else if(se75>=1000){lcd.print("75%   ");mem=75; } 
else if(se50>=1000){lcd.print("50%   ");mem=50; }
else if(se25>=1000){lcd.print("25%  ");mem=25; }
else{lcd.print("emty");mem=0;}
if(se100<1000&&se75<1000&&se50<1000&&se25<1000){
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    lcd.setCursor(12,1);
    lcd.print("emty");
}
```

My guess is that each of the analog readings comes from a different fluid sensor in a tank. If the top sensor shows a strong reading, the tank is considered full. Otherwise, it checks the next sensor down, and so on. If none of them shows a strong reading, the tank is considered empty. Interestingly, the condition for an empty tank is actually checked twice, which is presumably a mistake.

(Once again, bear in mind that I'm just guessing that the readings are from fluid sensors in a tank. I don't know for sure.)

The remainder of the code only runs if a particular input (#6) is low, and if the tank is not empty. Input #6 could be from some kind of override switch, but again that's just speculation.

The following block takes 6 analog readings, all from the same input. There's a short delay (20 millisecond) between each reading. The results are then averaged. This is a common approach when you want to try to eliminate noise spikes in an analog signal.

```
int tempa = analogRead(A1);
delay(20); 
int tempb = analogRead(A1);
delay(20); 
int tempc = analogRead(A1);
delay(20); 
int tempd = analogRead(A1);
delay(20); 
int tempe = analogRead(A1);
delay(20); 
int tempf = analogRead(A1);
delay(20); 

int avg = ((tempa + tempb + tempc + tempd + tempe + tempf ) / 6);
```

The next block re-maps that reading onto a different range (presumably related to the expected temperature range). It then takes another analog reading from a different input, and remaps that to a different range:

```
int temp = avg;  

temp = map(temp, 0, 1023, 0, 4900); 
float tempx = temp * (0.1); 

int tempy=analogRead(A0);
tempy = map(tempy, 0, 1023, 0, 150);
```

The following block outputs the two re-mapped readings. It looks like both of them are treated as temperatures. One is presumably from a temperature sensor, and the other is presumably from a potentiometer used to calibrated the system:

```
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("act T=" ); 
lcd.print(tempx);
lcd.print("'C  " );
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("set T=");  

lcd.print(tempy);  

lcd.print("'C  ");
```

These lines compare the two readings from above, and set output pin 13 high or low depending on which reading is higher. I'd guess it could be connected to a warning light or similar.

```
if(tempy<=tempx){digitalWrite(13,LOW);}
if(tempy>tempx){digitalWrite(13,HIGH);}
```

Lastly, this delay stops the loop from running too fast. Interestingly though, the code only reaches this point under certain circumstances. In other circumstances, there's no limit on loop execution speed:

```
delay(200);
```